# How to redirect a python import?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using 2 versions of Discord.py, a modified version to support self-bots and the original. Both use the same package name, discord. I have the modified discord.py for self-bots in `discord_py` folder

```
root
├─ discord_py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  └─ discord
│     ├─ __init__.py
│
└─ main.py
```

However this gives me import errors as the internals of `discord` also `import discord` resulting in conflict with the original, unmodified sys module `discord`.

Is there an init trick to redirect `import discord` in the `discord_py` folder to itself?

Comment: just change the name ?

Comment: `import .discord`?

Comment: @Grismar this doesn't solve the problem as the internal files also `import discord`. I was trying to not change all the imports in all the files

Answer (score 0):

If you're under linux, set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the location of the discord.py you wish to import.

And make sure to export it prior to running your program. Differing ides will allow you methods of doing this, but worst comes to worst you can set it from a shell, export it and then run your ide manually.

You can also use venv, which is easy-ish in PyCharm and manually specify where all your site packages will be.

So far as I know PYTHON_PATH works like PATH, in that it searches the locations defined in order, but not so, in that it searches these locations first and then your environments defaults.

Please see link [PYTHONPATH TUTORIAL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-PYTHONPATH-environment-variable-in-Python)

Comment: Would this cause conflict if I'm importing both versions of discord.py?